# Proverbs and saying for not achieving a specific situation (or objective)?

Tags: proverb, saying

I am looking for a set of Chinese 成语 and 俗语 describing ways in which a desired situation may not be achieved.

For instance, like the following two:

欲速则不达

东施效颦

Any others?

Where can I find a complete list?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are too many 俗語, 諺語 to list.

Here are few similar 成語 for you

> 揠苗助長 = 欲速則不達
>
> 適得其反 to the end, get opposite effect
>
> 事與願違 nothing comes out as planned

Comment: I think the phrase 事與願違  describes "a desired situation may not be achieved" well enough.